# Visual Studio 2015 'Output Window' highlight effect

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Maybe someone know how I could change this highlight effect in 'Output Window' of Visual Studio 2015

Here is example:

[image: Output window]

P.S. I have VSColorOutput extension installed but I checked twice that it does not set any background color.

Comment: it's seems that it not background. Brush style is not bsClear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is, in fact, a problem related to VSColorOutput and, according to the VSColorOutput's author, it's caused by a bug in Visual Studio.

You can see the whole conversation regarding this issue here: https://github.com/mike-ward/VSColorOutput/issues/4

In the meanwhile, you can try the workaround they propose there:
Go to Tools --> Options --> Environment --> Fonts and Colors

Show settings for:Output Window

Set Item background to Black (not Default or Automatic)

It worked for me after I restarted Visual Studio.

Comment: You suggestion was working couple of days but then something happens and the highlight color come back :( I didn't change anything :( I guess the VSColorOutput is very buggy so I will uninstall it

Comment: seems to be VS bug rather than this extension, see https://github.com/mike-ward/VSColorOutput/issues/4 there are possible solutions

Comment: Bugfix ripped from above issue page (in case it disappear): 

Tools --> Options --> Environment --> Fonts and Colors

Show settings for:Output WindowSet Item background to Black (not Default or Automatic) - that caused VSColorOutput's output background to switch immediately. Could it be that selecting "Default" or "Automatic" doesn't generate the color change notification you're referring to?